# Inherit a variable in isolated scope from parent scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Is it possible to access single variable from rootScope in directives isolated scope?

I understand using `scope: false` will inherit all the properties from parent scope and `scope: true` will create a new scope by inheriting all the properties from parent scope.

Can we inherit just one property from parent scope so that the directive can be more modular and cleaner.

Here is case I'm referring to.

index.html

```
<body ng-app="app">
    <header></header>
    <div ui-view=""></div>
</body>
```

directive.html

```
<div>Parent prop is {{parentProp}}</div>
```

directive.js

```
app.directive('header', function ($rootScope) {
        return {
            templateUrl: "temp.html"
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                parentProp: "@"
            },
            controller: function () {
                ...
            },
            bindToController: true,
            controllerAs: 'header'
        };
    });
```

app.js

```
app.run(function ($rootScope) {
        $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, next, nextParams) {
            $rootScope.parentProp = false;
            if(checkIfParentPropShouldBeTrue()) {
                $rootScope.parentProp = true;
            }
        });
    });
```

The `parentProp` property changes with state. Can I bind this property of `rootScope` to directive's isolated scope and manipulate directive's DOM respectively on every state change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define an isolate scope on a directive, it gets the values from attributes on the element of your directive.  In this case all you should have to do is "pass" parentProp to the directive, e.g. `<header parentProp="{{parentProp}}"></header>`

This is good because it makes your code more modular like you wanted.  You don't have to assume the value is attached to a scope, but can pass in anything from your scope or controller.

### After Comment from OP about doing without attributes

Try injecting $rootScope into into your directive's controller and then setting up a watch. I'm not sure this will work with an isolate scope

```
app.directive('header', function ($rootScope) {
    return {
        templateUrl: "temp.html"
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            parentProp: "@"
        },
        controller: function ($rootScope, $scope) {
            var unbindWatch = $rootScope.$watch('parentProp', function(value){
                $scope.parentProp = value;
            });
            //clean up watch when controller destroyed
            $scope.$on('$destroy', function(){
                unbindWatch();
            });
        },
        bindToController: true,
        controllerAs: 'header'
    };
});
```

Comment: This is the way. Here is a [plunker with a simple example](http://plnkr.co/edit/2IskU46hu5nwiBHIybaJ?p=preview)

Comment: Is there a way to achieve this without adding it as an attribute?

Comment: I think could inject $rootScope into your directive's controller and attach it to your isolate scope.  Basically your controller would be this function($rootScope, $scope){ $scope.parentProp = $rootScope.parentProp }

Comment: I tried that but unfortunately that doesn't bind the isolated scope value to the  `$rootScope` value

Comment: see edit.  I haven't tested and don't normally do things this way but I think it might work